# Windows delete many files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i'm trying to delete many files in many sub-folders with random extensions, how can i do that?
I have many encrypted files (ransomware), now i decrypted all files and i have a duplicate each file (30.000 files).

All encrypted files have a random name extensions with 6 characters
like "namefile.pdf.123456" / "namefile.docx.ujyrtf"

Can you help me to write e script to delete all these files?

Are stored in folder and sub-folders

Maybe i can try to use a Multiple File Renamer to rename *.jpg.* to *.jpg.del and then delete all *.del by cmd, i don't know if i can do this.

I try to use CMD's like this and i type:

```
del *.jpg.*
```

but this command deleted all `.jpg` and all `.jpg.*`

Thank you

ATTENTION: there aren't any legit files in these folders. It is a folder data with mkv, jpg, doc, xls, etc. Documents, Video, Audio. Not application or Windows Folder or something like that. Don't use this SCRIPT on system partition, program folders because there may be legit files that would be deleted. Thanks Gerard

Comment: The term "help" implies that you did some efforts on your own, so please [edit] your question and post a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Also take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask]!

Comment: you right aschipfl , i'm sorry, i edit question with cmd attempt.

Comment: The command line `dir /B /A:-D "*.*.*" | findstr /I "\...*\.[^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.]$"` should return the files you want to be deleted; use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture its output and to process the files, hence to delete them with `del`...

Comment: FWIW, that behaviour is expected: "[some MS-DOS quirks] ... persist into Win32 because they have become idiom.For example, if your pattern ends in .*, the .* is ignored. " [source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071217-00/?p=24143). You could use PowerShell, which does parse such patterns as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the files have a 6 digit extension then we can use a `findstr` `regex` to delete them.

from `cmd`

```
@for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /a-d *.????.* ^| findstr /r "\.[^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.]$"') do @echo del "%i"
```

or in a batch file:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Path to files\to delete\"
for /f %%i "delims=" in ('dir /b /a-d *.????.* ^| findstr /r "\.[^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.][^\.]$"') do echo del "%%i"
```

This will just echo the result, you need to remove `echo` only once you can confirm that it does not delete un-intended files.

Comment: Attention! False positives!! (files with more than one extension, like `*.x1.xls`) (also: there are legit files with six-char extension - not all of them are ransom-related and some might be crucial)

Comment: @Stephan. Thanks. I based this only on the comment by OP _"All encrypted files have a random name extensions with 6 characters"_ but will include option for extentions like `*.x1.xls`

Comment: @Stephan updated to exclude files with `*.x1.xls` possibilities

Comment: @9overvlow. There are still a lot of files with 6-char-extensions, that are false positives and may be essential for your applications or even Windows. Be extremely careful with deleting. (Sorry, but there just isn't a simple solution to your problem)

Comment: Rather than remove the `echo`, it may be better to capture the list of `del` commands to something like `deleteRansomFiles.bat`. The OP can then review that file, deleting any lines that represent false-positives. When they are happy, they can then run `deleteRansomFiles.bat` to clean their machine.

Comment: @9overflow Updated, please try it now. Please can we also remove some comments :)

Comment: Just add `/s` after `dir /b`

Comment: Thanks @9overflow, you may now delete your comments below this answer.